# file:inbound-channel-adapter fails when using a custom scanner

Tags: java, spring, file, integration

I am using spring integration 4.2.4.RELEASE and I came across a bug. I am trying to create a inbound-channel using a custom directory based on "WatchServiceDirectoryScanner". When I try to inject this scanner I get the error.

"The 'filter' and 'locker' options must be present on the provided external 'scanner': ". No matter what combination of properties I tried it does not work. The reason is because even I supply a locker and filters to my custom scanner the "FileReadingMessageSource" in spring creates their own. Therefore when the it asserts

```
Assert.state(!(this.scannerExplicitlySet && (this.filter != null || this.locker != null)),
                "The 'filter' and 'locker' options must be present on the provided external 'scanner': "
                        + this.scanner);
```

it fails. There is a filter being "FileListFilterFactoryBean.initializeFileListFilter" no matter what combination has been set the code below will create one and the whole things just fails.

```
        // no filters are provided
        else if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(this.preventDuplicates)) {
            filtersNeeded.add(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<File>());
        }
        else { // preventDuplicates is either TRUE or NULL
            filtersNeeded.add(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        }
```

I have read the post: [How to skip the settings of filter and locker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583113/how-to-skip-the-setting-of-filter-and-locker-attribute-if-custom-directorysc/33224194)
but it does not work for me.
Has anybody find a solution for this?

Here is a sample XML configuration of creating the inbound channel.

```
        <bean id="inboundChannel_3522_filter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.RegexPatternFileListFilter">
                    <constructor-arg value="^Test_(20160216).TXT$" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="inboundChannel_3522_nio_locker" class="org.springframework.integration.file.locking.NioFileLocker" />
    <bean id="inboundChannel_3522_scanner" class="com.test.spring.integraton.file.NonRecursiveWatchServiceDirectoryScanner"
>
        <constructor-arg value="e:\data\incoming\Test-V2" />
        <property name="filter" ref="inboundChannel_3522_filter"/> 
        <property name="locker" ref="inboundChannel_3522_nio_locker"/> 
    </bean>
    <file:inbound-channel-adapter  id="inboundChannel_3522"  auto-create-directory="true"  scanner="inboundChannel_3522_scanner" 
 directory="file:/c:/data/incoming/TEST/"  prevent-duplicates="false"  ignore-hidden="false"  >
        <integration:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Basically I want to know if there is any way to override the bean FileReadingMessageSource so that I can change the Assert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out how to get around this bug. So I create a scanner and I inject the filters and locker to the scanner. I create a custom FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean that skips creating filter and locker if a scanner has been injected. The CustomFileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean with the changes is shown below. The changes occurs at line 172. The rest it is the same.

```
            if (this.scanner != null)
        {
            this.source.setScanner(this.scanner);
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.filter != null)
            {
                if (this.locker == null)
                {
                    this.source.setFilter(this.filter);
                }
                else
                {
                    CompositeFileListFilter<File> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<File>();
                    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(this.filter);
                    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(this.locker);
                    this.source.setFilter(compositeFileListFilter);
                    this.source.setLocker(locker);
                }
            }
            else if (this.locker != null)
            {
                CompositeFileListFilter<File> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<File>();
                compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new FileListFilterFactoryBean().getObject());
                compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(this.locker);
                this.source.setFilter(compositeFileListFilter);
                this.source.setLocker(locker);
            }
        }
```

The new Spring XML looks as below. The difference is that we add the bean inboundChanel_3522.adapter.source at the end. What this does is when the inbound channel looks for a bean of type FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean it will append to its id the ".adpater.source" and if one exist it will use that otherwise it will create a default. In this case it will use our CustomFileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean which has the logic to skip creating additional filters. It is very important that the custom bean comes after inbound-channel-adapter otherwise the bean factory will override it. Finally here is how the XML should look like.

```
 <bean id="inboundChannel_3522_filter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
     <constructor-arg>
         <list>
             <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.RegexPatternFileListFilter">
                 <constructor-arg value="^Test_(20160216).TXT$" />
             </bean>
         </list>
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="inboundChannel_3522_nio_locker" class="org.springframework.integration.file.locking.NioFileLocker" />
<bean id="inboundChannel_3522_scanner" class="com.test.spring.integraton.file.NonRecursiveWatchServiceDirectoryScanner">
    <constructor-arg value="e:\data\incoming\Test-V2" />
    <property name="filter" ref="inboundChannel_3522_filter"/> 
    <property name="locker" ref="inboundChannel_3522_nio_locker"/> 
</bean>
<file:inbound-channel-adapter  id="inboundChannel_3522"  auto-create-directory="true"  
    scanner="inboundChannel_3522_scanner" 
    directory="file:/c:/data/incoming/TEST/"  prevent-duplicates="false"  ignore-hidden="false"  >
    <integration:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<bean id="inboundChannel_3522.adapter.source" class="com.test.spring.integraton.file.CustomFileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean">
    <property name="scanner" ref="inboundChannel_3522_scanner"/> 
    <property name="directory" value="e:\data\incoming\Test-V2"/> 
    <property name="autoCreateDirectory" value="true"/> 
</bean>
```